# Random crashes after BIOS Update on ASRock MB

Tags: cpu, bios, crash

After updating my BIOS from 4.6 to 5.6, my PC started to randomly crash without Bluescreen. I have an ASRock X370 Taichi with an formerly overclocked Ryzen 1600 and a GTX 1080. Resetting the OC and restoring default settings made the crashes even more frequent. Windows Event Log throws errors related to Kernel-Processor-Power [The Error in the Windows Event Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLkX2.png). The time between crashes varies from a few minutes to a few hours. Stressing the processor with CPU-Zs stresser hasn't provokes a crash yet. Before the BIOS update everything worked fine. The only idea I have left is to try to downgrade the BIOS. Any better ideas or tips how to do that?

Comment: I would update all the other drivers, particularly Video. See if the computer manufacturer has a driver update application and run that. Otherwise look on the support site for your model and get all the drivers. See if remaining driver updates fix the issue.

Comment: It's a 2 years old custom build. I installed Ryzen Master and Nvidia Experience so at least GPU and CPU should be fine. The crashes only started happening after the BIOS update. I assume, that somehow the power management for the CPU got messed up in the new version. But rising the power limit didn't help

Comment: See if you can roll back the BIOS to a prior version. I am not sure what else to suggest here.

Comment: Have you done something like this before? The manufacturer says on the product page that: " User will not able to flash previous BIOS once upgrading to this BIOS version." I saw a video of someone downgrading his x470 Taichi, but like it stands, chances are high that I would brick it.

Comment: From the product page it seems to go from 4.6 to 5.6 you have to first flash Bridge BIOS 5.10. Was this done you or directly went from 4.6 to 5.6? If you have a spare storage device like another SATA HDD or SSD, try a clean install of your Windows (I assume it would be Windows 10) on that, see if it succeeds and if so, then install all latest drivers and observe system stability.  Ryzen 5 1600 is Summit Ridge so going beyond 5.6 is again not recommended by ASRock.

Comment: I have not rolled back a BIOS in a very, very long time, so I do not know whether it will work in this case or not.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yes, I flashed the bridge bios. I have no experience installing multiple Windows installations on the same machine. Are there any license issues or does it just install without messing up my old install? What about a Linux live system? You think it's suitable for testing?

Comment: What I meant to say is not a Dual Boot Windows 10 & Windows 10 but in case you have a spare HDD/SSD then disconnect the current one, attach another and do a clean Windows 10 install just to check the system stability. Live Linux just running off USB and RAM may not give reliable idea. However you may consider installing Linux alongside Windows 10 as a Dual boot config and observe how it behaves. Continued...

Comment: Assuming you have UEFI boot, Linux will install its bootloader on EFI partition in a separate folder and you will have to preferably manually create/specify 'root' partition in free space during Linux installation  to ensure that it does not affect current Windows 10. You might need to disable Secure Boot in Firmware settings (BIOS)

Comment: So I can pull out my drives, install Windows on a new drive and afterwards plug my old ones in without license or other issues?

Comment: The computer was running Windows 10, so yes, you can install a new drive, install Windows 10 and it will definitely activate. The licensing is held in the Microsoft Licensing Server.

Comment: New Windows install, few hours in, so far no crashes. I was so focused on the new BIOS, I forgot to mention that I installed Ryzen Master at the same time. I uninstalled it shortly after because it didn't let me go back to standard CPU clocks. Maybe that messed up my system. Any chance I can save my old system? I put way to much time and effort in it to replace it easily with a fresh install. By the way, I just installed Windows and the NVIDIA Control Panel so far. No other drivers.

Comment: I just suggest that, run it for a day or two, run stress test using Prime 95 or so and then make some conclusions. Also avoid any bloatwares provided by vendors. Wherever possible, just keep it to the default or vendor specific drivers. If everything looks good, take important data backup from your original HDD/SSD system drive e.g. if you have anything important personal files stored on that system drive c: from original drive. Then disconnect the test drive, keep only original connected and  see if it boots into original Windows. You might need to recreate boot entry into UEFI. Continued…

Comment: …Then try System refresh (Reset this PC) option from Settings – Recovery option and decide if you want to keep your files and apps or do a clean reset. First try ‘Keep my Files’ and if that does not help, try ‘Remove Everything’.  No matter what, opt for ‘Remove files only from the drive where Windows is installed’, else it will wipe the entire HDD/SSD and you will lose all other partitions.

Comment: After over a month without trouble, the same problem returned. I tested my PSU with Aida 64, voltages looks extremely stable under full load. I didn't install any software which should be able to affect system stability. As it stands, I have no idea why it came back.